# Solution clarification for the question: Prove that a group of order 33 contains an element of order 3

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For the following question:

Prove that a group of order 33 contains an element of order 3.

From the student solution manual, the solution reads as follows:

> Suppose $|G|=33$ and $G$ has no element of order 3.  Then by Theorem 7.8 there is no element of order 33, and Lagrange implies that every nonidentity element has order 11.  Count the number of subgroups of order 11 to obtain a contradiction.

My question about the solution is as follows: 
By counting the elements of order 11, what contradiction am I suppose to obtain.  Since my understanding is that by a corollary to Lagrange theorem (which is from a different text), that

> In a finite group, the number of element of order $d$ is a multiple of $\phi(d)$. (Euler's Totient function)

Hence for $d=11$, we have $\phi(11)=10.$, and there are at most 30 of them.  Lagrange theorem does not imply that a group of finite order must have elements of order 11.  But since there are 30 elements of order 11. What contradiction am I suppose to be deriving from this conclusion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You wrote: "the order of an element order d is a multiple of ϕ(d)". It is logically incorrect.

Comment: @HamidEnki thank you for pointing out my typo.  I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: By Lagrange the possible orders of elements are $1$, $3$, $11$, $33$: only the identity has order $1$ and $3$, $33$ are excluded: wo we have $32$ elements of order $11$; but these lie in subgroups of prime order $11$ which don't overlap, so that there are $10k$ elements of order $11$: contradiction.

Comment: @ancientmathematician but can the group $G$ of order 33 have 30 elements of order 11 and not 32.  I mean, if so, then won't a proof by contradiction be avoided?

Comment: Use Cauchy's Theorem. The proof is a little difficult to understand at first, but it can be really helpful: Given a group $G$, and a prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, we must have at least one element of order $p$. However, since all groups of order $p$ are cyclic, we must have such a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @J.Linne I am not sure that the group $G$ must have a group of order 3 if I use cauchy's theorem.  Both 3 and 11 are primes.  So Cauchy's theorem applies to both cases.  But does it mean simply because p is prime, a finite group must contains subgroup of order p, and in this case subgroups of both order 3 and 11?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Any group of order $33$ must necessarily have elements of order $3$ and $11$. We must have $2$ such elements of order $3$, and $10$ of order $11$.

Comment: @J.Linne can't it have 30 elements of order 11?  I mean what orders are each of the other 20 elements suppose to have. They could be either 3 or 11 and as long as they total to a multiples of $\phi(3)$ and $\phi(11)$ respectively?

Comment: No they can't (Hint: look up the Sylow theorems, specifically the third one). Even if they could, you still have $33 - 3*10 - 1 = 2$ elements uncounted for. They must be of order $3$. Any group of order $33$ is isorpmorphic to $\mathbb{Z} 33$ and cyclic.

Comment: @J.Linne I haven't learn Sylow theorem yet.  Is the solution from the student manual to be interpret to mean that a group of order 33 can't have only subgroups of order 11 but it can have subgroups of order of both 3 and 11?

Comment: You don't need Sylow, Cauchy, whatever. Just as I said Lagrange plus the fact that the elements of order $11$ (which is prime) lie in subgroups of order $11$ which don't intersect except in the identity: so that the number of elements of order $11$ is $10k$. As $33\ne 10k+1$ you can't just have elements of order $11$ (plus the identity).

Comment: @ancientmathematician I understand your explanations now   I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661610/show-that-a-group-with-g-33-contains-an-element-of-order-3?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you for the  reference link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Assume $G$ has no element of order $3$. Then all of it's elements are either of order $1$ or $11$. But as you said correctly, the number of elements of order $11$ must be a multiple of $\phi(11)$ ( for proof see Gallian's contemporary abstract algebra). Then you have $3\cdot \phi(11)=3\cdot 10 =30$ elements of order $11$. And one element is the identity which has order $1$. This leaves you with a group of $31$ elements and not $33$. Contradiction.

Let me explain the flow of logic leading to such a conclusion.

step 0:- Apriori we cannot say how many elements are there of order 11 or 3 are in the group. All we have in hand is this theorem which says that the number of elements of order $d$ must be a multiple of $\phi(d)$.

Step 1:- Assume that there are no elements of order $3$.

step 2:- This leads to the conclusion that there must be atleast one element of order $11$. Of course all 33 elements cannot be identity duh!.

Step 3:- Now applying the theorem we have the number of elements of order $11$ are eithe $10,20$ or $30$. In all three cases you fall short of the number $33$ .

Step 4:- You conclude that your assumption was false and there must exist an element of order $3$.

Now let me explain how you cannot avoid proof by contradiction if you only know apriori Lagrange's theorem and that corollary. If you go about trying to classify the types of orders of elements are there in a group of order $33$ you end up with the following three possibilities :-

If there does exist an element of order $11$ then you have by arguing as Gallian does that you will end up with $10,20$ or $30$ elements of order $11$.  Thus in this case you have to conclude that the remaining elements except the identity have to be of order $3$. Done !

If there does not exist an element of order $11$ then you must have $32$ elements of order $3$ in a group of order $33$ and hence you are done as you have proven there exists one(again all of them cannot be identity). Mind you that although this conclusion is absolutely mental, keeping in view bit more advanced theorems like Cauchy or Sylow and many other results ,you are not actually ending up violating what you have assumed to be true apriori. And thus you are done. This is obviously not very clean but because you are not breaking the logical flow and arriving to the conclusion you set out to prove , this suffices and proves the claim that there must exist one element of order $3$.

2. Use Cauchy's Theorem. If $p$ is a prime and $p$ divides $|G|$ then it has an element of order $p$.

3.Sylow's Theorem. If $p^{r}\,,r\geq 1$ divides $|G|$ then it has a subgroup of order $p^{r}$. From here you can conclude that the subgroup has an element of order $3$ as it is cyclic.

Comment: Of course this is correct but it seems to me to be far too deep for such a trivial result!

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron in Gallian's solution on the same question, he states that if $G$ has no elements of order 33, it has 30 elements of order 11 plus the identity element, then the remaining two elements must have order 3.  The proof by contradictions is avoided entirely.  I was initially confused as to whether $G$ can have order 11 if it has order 3.  I was not aware of the result having to do with the euler totient function until I consulted Gallian's text.

Comment: @SethMai you are not avoiding proof by contradiction. To conclude that $G$ has 30 elements of order $30$ you need to know the result that the elements of order $d$ occurs in multiples of $\phi(d)$. Thereafter you are eliminating the cases and if you assume that it has no elements of order $3$ , you then end up with a contradiction. Mind you there is no Structure Theorem here. The group may be abelian or non-abelian. So you cannot apriori predict that it has $30$ elements of order 11. I'll explain it in a bit more detail.

Comment: @SethMai I have edited in more details to make it clear. Please check

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thaank you for the clarification.  When I wrote out the proof by contradiction, the text did not even talk about the result concerning totient function.  I  only had to work with Lagrange theorem.  So I wasn't sure if the case that it has elements of order 3, then, can it still have elements of order 11.  Also, I wasn't sure when I see Cauchy's theorem, it has to do with the the existent of elements of order p as subgroups when p is prime....

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron ...the theorem call Cauchy's theorem in the text I am using refers to finite group isomorphic to a permutation group.   Finally, i want to know the answer about the case about order 11 or wanting to understand where is the contradiction because i wasn't sure how to count the number of elements in a finite group when the order of those elements have order p for p being prime.  That was before I was made aware of what or which theory Cauchy's theorem refers to.

Comment: Hang on.....That is Cayley's Theorem. Please rechek....I know...I too confuse their names often .  This is Cauchy's theorem . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Statement_and_proof .  This is Cayley's theorem . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron sorry for the late reply.  I just saw saw your comment now.  I keep getting Cauchy and Cayley mixed up.  I just want to be clear for myself, Cauchy's theorem means that for a given prime $p$, and a finite group $G$ of order $n$.  If $p$ appears in the factorization of $n$, then Cauchy's theorem means that there must be an element in the group $G$ of order $p$.  As for the corollary to Lagrange's theorem in Gallian text, it means that  the number of element of order $p$ in $G$, if it has any at all, is $k\phi(p)$. where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k\geq 1$.